# How to obtain project quotas states (ssd disks, cpu)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I try to obtain project quotas info for my GCP projects via gcloud or API:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project [my-project-id]
```

Unfortunately there is no data for CPUs and ssd disks.
I tried to use different versions of gcloud (alpha|beta) but with no result.

How can I get such data from GCP without the Google Cloud Console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order [to retrieve information regarding regional quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) you have to run:

```
$ gcloud compute regions describe example-region
```

For example running it in my test project:

```
gcloud compute regions describe us-central1

[...]
metric: SSD_TOTAL_GB
usage: 45.0
- limit: 6000.0
[...]
metric: PREEMPTIBLE_CPUS
usage: 0.0
- limit: 1.0
```